# iCloud Backup: "The last backup could not be completed"

Tags: backup, icloud

I don't exactly remember when this started but my iPad running iOS 5 started not doing backups to iCloud. When I press the "Back Up Now" button it starts working for a few seconds but then stops and shows the message from the title beneath the button.

I already tried reseting, restoring, deleting my iCloud account from the settings, using another iCloud account and now I'm pretty devastated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out now.

After getting to replace my iPad due to a hardware defect I installed the iOS beta I have been using before and forgot to register the new device as a developer device as well.
Stupid mistake, took me weeks to identify the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for answering this - would you also mark this answer as accepted? It helps the site since your question is still flagged an unanswered.

Comment: Whoops, totally overlooked your comment. Better late than never...

Comment: The Internet is forever, so you are well ahead of the cutoff time to mark this accepted.

Comment: This is also the case for non-beta OS installs. I had the same issue after replacing my phone and am just using the latest non-developer OS version as installed by iTunes. Thank you for figuring it out!

Comment: So if your phone is not running IOS beta, how is this the solution?

Comment: I am developer and I can't backup my iOS 8.4.1 device to iTunes and iCloud. How can I register my device. Is in in iTunes Connect or Xcode?

Comment: @borisy It's in the Member Center

Comment: @LukasSpieß Thanks, I renewed my devices. For some reason I had duplicate for my Apple Watch. I deleted the duplicate (it has same UDID, so I didn't know which one to disable). But I still can't backup to iTunes. Should I disable my Apple Watch and re-add it again?

Comment: @LukasSpieß don't mind, this wasn't related to Member Center. I had 2 corrupted apps on my iPhone which couldn't be deleted. I had to re-download them and now backup works.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backip and turn off iCloud backup. Backup/Sync to your computer and then turn iCloud backup on the device back on.

Comment: Already tried this and didn't work.

Comment: Out of curiosity how old is your Apple ID? I have a very old @mac.com Apple ID and found that I had to create a new Apple ID to get iCloud backup to work.

Comment: My Apple ID is actually an a few years old @gmail.com adress.